# How to properly clean up a Windows Service and its account?

Tags: windows, service, code-cleanup

We have this service that needs some special file permissions and we are therefor running the service within his own virtual service account:

1. The service exe is installed using installutil.exe c:\path_to\MyService.exe
2. The service installation is done using LOCALSYSTEM
3. Last step in the serviceinstaller, the logon account is switched to "NT SERVICE\MyService"

All works well but because the service is used as an account that runs the service, a windows profile is created & used.

When the service is removed with command line installutil.exe /u c:\path_to\MyService.exe a bunch of files & registry keys remain:

- %SystemRoot%\ServiceProfiles\LansweeperLocalDbService
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\Cache\S-1-5-80-3871198407-3985681096-187537395-327373503-1498934226
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
  NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileService\References\S-1-5-80-3871198407-3985681096-187537395-327373503-1498934226
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
  Search\UninstalledStoreApps\S-1-5-80-3871198407-3985681096-187537395-327373503-1498934226
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows
  Search\UninstalledStoreApps\S-1-5-80-3871198407-3985681096-187537395-327373503-1498934226
- HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-80-3871198407-3985681096-187537395-327373503-1498934226
- HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-80-3871198407-3985681096-187537395-327373503-1498934226_Classes

When the uninstall is complete and the service has been removed, "NT SERVICE\MyService" is still listed within the System > Advanced > User Profiles and it cannot be deleted.

After a reboot, this profile is listed as "Account Unknown" and while the profile can be manually deleted, the registry keys and files remain and some keys seem to be locked.

Only after I have manually removed that "Account Unknown profile" using the GUI and reboot my machine, the registry keys & files are gone. Even in this stage I fail to manually remove some registry keys because of access denied (or in use?).

How should and can I properly automate the removal of the service account??